# OS 0.4.1 - Brazilian Portuguese keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm trying to setup my keyboard layout to Brazilian Portuguese.

In Brazil, some words need accents (café, jóia, etc..) and I'm trying all available keyboard layout and language configurations, including to change the default OS language, without good results.

I'm running Elementary inside Oracle Virtual box.

Regards,

Alexandre

Answer (score 1):

Open Slingshot and search for "Keyboard", click on the highlighted result:

[image: Slingshot]

Search for Portuguese (Brazil) and add it as a Layout.

[image: Keyboard settings]

Now you can add accents!

[image: Testing the keyboard layout]

Comment: Hi Fultie. It's working. Thank you for the support.

Comment: @Alexandre I'm glad! Please mark the answer as accepted to help the site reduce its number of questions without an accepted answer. :)